# How can I validate an array of mongoDB object Ids?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a REST API record collection using Node, Express, and MongoDB where the user can add artists, add records, add records to artists, and add artists to records.

Here is my "SUBMIT RECORD" post request, where "artists" is an array of object ids that reference already created artist objects. However, right now, you can add a record with invalid artist IDs (i.e. IDs for artists that don't exist).

Is there a way to validate each element in the array of artist IDs *before* saving it (i.e. validating each ID belongs to an artist object)?

```
// TODO: VALIDATE ALL ARTISTS EXIST BEFORE ADDING RECORD
router.post('/records', async (req, res) => {
    let record = new Record({
        name: req.body.name,
        releaseDate: req.body.releaseDate,
        link: req.body.link,
        artists: req.body.artists
    });
    try {
        const savedRecord = await record.save();

        // UPDATE ARTIST
         const artist = record.artists.map(element => Artist.updateOne({_id: element}, {$push: {records: record}}));
         await Promise.all(artist);

        res.status(200).json(savedRecord);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({message: err.message});
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you asking how to search for artists from the list and count the results?

Comment: @AlexBlex How to ensure that the artist IDs in each record are for artists that actually exist.

Comment: Search artists with ids from the list and count the results. I guess the search result will give you the list of artists that actually exist. If number of artists in the result matches number of ids the validation is passed. If number of artists is less than number of ids, it means not all artists exist and validation is failed. If number of documents is greater than number of ids than the ids are not unique and there are serious problems with data integrity.